# Truncate dictionary from tkvar.get()

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tkinter

***I have created a Tkinter window with two drop down menus that allow the user to select a start month and end month to calculate data within the set range (see below):***

```
from tkinter import *
from pandas import Timestamp

root = Tk()
root.title("Select your Month Range")

# Setting up Grid
mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.pack(pady=50, padx=50)
Label(mainframe, text="Select Start Month").grid(row=1, column=1)
Label(mainframe, text="Select End Month").grid(row=1, column=6)

# Creating two Tkinter variables to obtain user input from the drop down menus
tkvar_start = StringVar(root)
tkvar_end = StringVar(root)
tkvar_start.set('Jan 17')  # Setting a default option
tkvar_end.set(endDate)

start_popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar_start, *dict_months)
end_popupMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar_end, *dict_months)
start_popupMenu.grid(row=2, column=1)
end_popupMenu.grid(row=2, column=6)

def callback_range():
    print('The range is from %s to %s' % (tkvar_start.get(), tkvar_end.get()))
    #range_dict_months = dict(itertools.islice(dict_months.items(), 3))

button = Button(mainframe, text = "OK", command = callback_range)
button.grid(row=3, column=23)
```

The above code produces this window, except the default option is Jul 18 rather than March, I took a screenshot of my window after testing my code:

[image: Above code produces this window]

My dictionary for the two popup menus, `dict_months` is:

```
>>> dict_months
    {'Jan 17': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Feb 17': Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Mar 17': Timestamp('2017-03-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Apr 17': Timestamp('2017-04-01 00:00:00'), 
    'May 17': Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Jun 17': Timestamp('2017-06-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Jul 17': Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Aug 17': Timestamp('2017-08-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Sep 17': Timestamp('2017-09-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Oct 17': Timestamp('2017-10-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Nov 17': Timestamp('2017-11-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Dec 17': Timestamp('2017-12-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Jan 18': Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Feb 18': Timestamp('2018-02-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Mar 18': Timestamp('2018-03-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Apr 18': Timestamp('2018-04-01 00:00:00'), 
    'May 18': Timestamp('2018-05-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Jun 18': Timestamp('2018-06-01 00:00:00'), 
    'Jul 18': Timestamp('2018-07-01 00:00:00')}
```

**I would like to alter my `callback_range()` function to include truncating/slicing a dictionary from the user's input. For example, if the user selects Jan 17 to Mar 17 like in the picture, the desired output should be:**

```
>>> dict
{'Jan 17': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 
'Feb 17': Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00'), 
'Mar 17': Timestamp('2017-03-01 00:00:00')}
```

How can I use `tkvar_start.get()` and `tkvar_end.get()` to truncate the dictionary, and include the months in between the dictionary? A dictionary is not iterable, and I could be wrong, but using `iterslice` seems to require the use of indices.

`islice(sequence, start, stop, step)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this might not be the best way to do it, but you can do something like the following:

```
def callback_range():
    list_of_keys  = list(dict_months.keys())    
    # approach 1
    range_dict = { k:dict_months[k] for k in list_of_keys[list_of_keys.index(tkvar_start.get()):list_of_keys.index(tkvar_end.get())+1]} 
    print(range_dict)
    # approach 2
    import itertools
    range_dict = dict(itertools.islice(dict_months.items(),list_of_keys.index(tkvar_start.get()), list_of_keys.index(tkvar_end.get())+1)) 
    print(range_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Jan 17': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Feb 17': Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00'), 'Mar 17': Timestamp('2017-03-01 00:00:00')}
{'Jan 17': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Feb 17': Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00'), 'Mar 17': Timestamp('2017-03-01 00:00:00')}
```